# React Native: Flash Message memory leak error

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, flash-message

I am using [Flash Message](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-flash-message) in React Native. A memory leak error is thrown when I navigate to another screen without waiting for the message to disappear.

#### Code

```
showMessage({
  message: "Hello World",
  duration: 2000,
  description: "This is our second message",
  type: "success",
});
```

#### Error

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, the componentWillUnmount method,
```

Comment: Does this library even have cleanup method? I don't think so. Cleanup is usually required for listeners and async operations, and I don't seem to find this method anywhere near to that. Could you share more insight on what you're trying to achieve actually?

Comment: @VinaySharma No this library doesn't have cleanup method. If I don't wait flash message disappear and I go to another page, I get this error.

Comment: Did you use it globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wait for flash message to disappear. You can hide the message programmatically before navigating to a new screen.

#### Code

```
// import hideMessage method from the library
import { hideMessage } from "react-native-flash-message";

// a function which navigates to another screen
foo = () => {
  // assuming you are using react navigation
  // in a class based component
  const { navigation } = this.props;

  // call hideMessage before you navigate
  hideMessage();
  navigation.navigate('ScreenName');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution with the useEffect()

```
import { hideMessage } from "react-native-flash-message";


  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      hideMessage()
    }
  }, [])
```